# polymorphic and destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, polymorphism

I just wrote some codes and I'm trying to understand how objects are destructed polymorphically.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {
        std::cout << "base destructed\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base{
virtual ~Derived() {
    std::cout << "derived destructed\n";
}
};

int main() {
  Derived der;
  Base bases1[2], bases2[2], bases3[2], bases4[2];
  //case 1
  new(bases1) Derived(der);
  std::cout << "((Base*)bases1)->~Base();\n";
  ((Base*)bases1)->~Base();
  //case 2
  new(bases2) Derived(der);
  std::cout << "\nbases2->~Base();\n";
  bases2->~Base();
  //case 3
  new(bases3) Derived(der);
  std::cout << "\nbases3[0].~Base();\n"; 
  bases3[0].~Base();
  //case 4
  new(bases4) Derived(der);
  std::cout << "\n(*bases4).~Base();\n";    
  (*bases4).~Base();

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

### **What I know about the above codes:**

1. In case 1, bases1 points to the begining of a Derived object(include a vptr), and it's a base pointer, so it's just like the usual case we delete on a base pointer(I mean the destruction).
2. In case 2, bases2 is an array name, but in some cases we can treat it as a pointer that points to the first object, so case 2 should give me the same result as case 1?
3. Case 3, and case 4 are identical, they both dereference the first object, which have the type: Base, and then call the destructor on it.
4. These codes are non-standard, and dangerous, but I just want to figure out how it works on a specified compiler(visual studio 2012).

output:

```
((Base*)bases1)->~Base();
derived destructed
base destructed

bases2->~Base();

bases3[0].~Base();
base destructed

(*bases4).~Base();
base destructed
```

### **What I want to know:**

1. In case 2, nothing is destructed, what are the possible reasons? compiler optimization?
2. In casse 3, and case 4, only the bases are destructed, how comes? object slicing?

### Edit:

The following is what I got from the Disassembly window:

```
 ((Base*)bases1)->~Base();
00D96CF9  mov         esi,esp  
00D96CFB  push        0  
00D96CFD  mov         eax,dword ptr [bases1]  
00D96D00  lea         ecx,[bases1]  
00D96D03  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
00D96D05  call        edx  
00D96D07  cmp         esi,esp  
00D96D09  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (0D91992h)

  bases2->~Base(); //empty

  bases3[0].~Base();
00D96DB0  push        0  
00D96DB2  mov         eax,4  
00D96DB7  imul        eax,eax,0  
00D96DBA  lea         ecx,bases3[eax]  
00D96DBE  call        Base::`vector deleting destructor' (0D91A0Ah) //array delete?

  (*bases4).~Base();
00D96E14  push        0  
00D96E16  mov         eax,4  
00D96E1B  imul        eax,eax,0  
00D96E1E  lea         ecx,bases4[eax]  
00D96E22  call        Base::`vector deleting destructor' (0D91A0Ah)  //aray delete?
```

I can't read assembler, can someone give me a reasonable explanation from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
new(bases1) Derived(der);
```

Undefined behavior. `bases1` is an array of `Base`. Stuffing an object of type `Derived` into it doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: Undefined behavior is a much stronger statement than "non-standard". Unless you compiler documents what it does, you're just guessing based on behavior with a particular version of the compiler and a particular set of compiler options. In fact, you (and I) don't know **anything** about what this code will do.